# Optimize MySQL query to find last visit id using latest visit date

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

Running on AWS Aurora MySQL 8.0

I have a visit_data table of _record_id, location_id, visit_date.

I need to provide the query a list of location_id and determine if one of those location_id was the last visit for any of the record_id.

I do have a functional query that does work and in production but performance is very slow.

```
SELECT 
    ud.record_id, 
    vd.location_id
  FROM
    user_data as ud
    visit_data as vd
  WHERE ud.record_id = vd._record_id
    AND vd._campaign_id in (123)
    AND vd.location_id = (SELECT
                          pvd.location_id
                        FROM
                          visit_data as pvd
                        WHERE
                          pvd._campaign_id in (123)
                          AND pvd._record_id = ud.record_id
                          AND pvd.location_id IN ('location-1', 'location-2',
                                         'location-3', 'location-4',
                                         'location-5', 'location-1800')
                       ORDER BY pvd.visit_date DESC
                        LIMIT 1)
    AND vd.location_id IN ('location-1', 'location-2',
                    'location-3', 'location-4',
                    'location-5', 'location-1800')
    AND vd.visit_date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2024-01-31'
  GROUP BY ud.record_id
```

I do get the expected results however on a table with only little over 2 million records, it is taking upwards of 60 seconds.

I have used all the permutation of indexes using record_id (rid), campaign_id (cid), poi and visit_date, keeping visit_date last. I could think and I just can't seem to get the right combination.

| select_type | table | type | possible_key | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Primary | rd | range |  | _poi__visit_date__index | 770 |  | 105917 | 9.5 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary |
| Primary | fd | eq_ref | Primary | Primary | 4 |  | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| Dependent | pvd | ref |  | _cid__rid__index | 4 |  | 3 | 12.17 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |

I am hoping there is some strategic logic I am not seeing and using the right query structure that some else might see.

I hope I provided enough info to help.

Thanks
--FS

Comment: do i get it right that for each user you need to select the most recent visit, which comes from a specific campaign (123), one of 6 specific locations (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1800) and in a specific date range? specifically, do you want 1 row per user or 6 rows per user (1 row for every location_id)?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name for EVERY table involved.  It is likely you are not using any index with multiple columns to expedite the selection request.

Comment: The EXPLAIN results did not come from the query posted. The short names of the tables listed in explain are not in the query. Please post the real query, not something else.  And a current EXPLAIN SELECT .......

Comment: Smells like a groupwise-max problem.

Comment: I have read the replies and thanks.  I will provide the extra data, which makes perfect sense.  @RickJames, I am not sure what groupwise-max is, but it is MY problem. ;).

Comment: @FutureShock - I added a [tag]; also see my blog:  [_Groupwise-Max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)